# fetch() on $results returns boolean

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am attempting to fetch my row of results in an array. When I run the code, it tells me the following:

```
Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in file.php on line 69
```

I am doing the following

```
$query =  "INSERT INTO table(info) VALUES(:info)";

$params = array(':info' => $_POST['info']);

try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Insertion Error. Please Try Again";
    echo $response["error_msg"];
    die(json_encode($response));
}

while($row = $result->fetch()) {

}

echo $row["info"];
```

I am new to PHP so I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here. I can clarify anything if necessary. All Help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to understand that `INSERT` query doesn't  return anything form the database, it returns only `true or false` based on successful execution. `SELECT` query  will going to return a `resultset object` of bunch of rows from your database. On that you can apply `fetch()`.

Answer (score 0):

Insert does not return anything. It will if you edit your query to a `SELECT` statement like such:

```
SELECT * FROM info.
```

also put the `$row["info"]` inside the while, because the while repeats itself untill there is nothing to fetch. meaning it will print `$row["info"]` for all your database rows.